# Java Logic to update string depending on code received

Tags: java, java-8

I have a scenario where in we get machine code from one machine that needs to be sent to another but by converting it to string which other machine understands following are the scenarios

```
**if code is 'AGO PRF' then convert to 'AGO.P'
if code is 'HUSQ A' then convert to 'HUSQ.A'
if code is 'AIK B' then convert to 'AIK.B'
if code is 'ALUS WS' then convert to 'ALUS.WS'
if code is 'VST WSA' then convert to 'VST.WSA'
if code is 'SAB CL' then convert to 'SAB.CL'
if code is 'SPR WSB' then convert to 'NSPR.WSB'
if code is 'AXS PRD CL' then change it to 'AXS.PCL'
if code is 'CTEST RT' then convert to 'CTEST.R'
if code is 'ALUS U' then convert to 'ALUS.U'
if code is 'SFUN WI' then convert to 'SFUN.WI'
if code is 'RQI RT WI' then convert to 'RQI.RTWI'
if code is 'ECA WS WI' then change it to 'ECA.WSWI'.**
```

I used a MAP to fed in these values as keys and give out the output. but I want to know if there can be more generic solution to this

Comment: There may be a more generic solution, but it depends what this function actually does. If you know that these are the only inputs you have to handle, then a map is probably the simplest and best performing solution

Comment: @cameron1024 - Yes but it might happen this valus may change in future or more values added so just wanted to know.

Comment: Store them in a table

Comment: If you can describe the logic (or rule set) behind the conversion, you can implement right that logic. Otherwise, there is nothing more generic than a map.

Answer (score 1):

If there exists neither a rule nor a regularity of the String replacement (I find none), then you need either a mapping table stored in the DB or a static `Map<String, String>` of these constants:

- I recommend the `Map` in case of a small number of these and they would not be changed often.
- I recommend reading from the DB in case of a larger number of these. This also allows you to change the mapping on run with no need to build and redeploy the entire application.

In terms of the data structure, the dictionary-based would be the best way to go - `Map<String, String>`. It doesn't allow you to store duplicated keys and is simple to use for the transformation:

```
List<String> listOfStringsToBeReplaced = loadFromSomewhere();
Map<String, String> map = loadFromDb();

List<String> listWithReplacedStrnigs = listOfStringsToBeReplaced.stream()
    .map(string -> map.getOrDefault(string, string))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I use [`Map::getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) to either replace the value or keep it as is if no mapping is found.